# How to remove the brackets from the list within the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, visual-studio

```
p = [[10,10,10],[11,11,11]]
for i in range(0,2):
    print("progress = ",p[i])
```

When I print this i get -

```
progress =  [10, 10, 10]
progress =  [11, 11, 11]
```

I want to remove the brackets from the above list

Comment: That's what the string representation of a `list` looks like.  Are you just looking to print without displaying it as a list?  Do you always have the same number of sub-lists and elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `p[i]` with

```
(", ".join([str(x) for x in p[i]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The i values in the for loop are inner lists. To remove the brackets, unpack the list using *. Your code:

```
p = [[10,10,10],[11,11,11]]
for i in range(0,2):
    print("progress = ",*p[i])
```

Comment: This also removes the commas.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to remove the brackets from the list:

```
  p = [[10,10,10],[11,11,11]]
  for i in range(0,2):
    print(str(p[i])[1:-1])
```